# After baking, bread coated with shiny residue

Tags: baking, bread, non-stick

Started making sourdough bread at home. Baked last night in non-stick pans (Cuisinart, Xylan coating, I think) and left to cool off overnight.

This morning, I took a look at the bread, and it's coated in metallic-like shiny gray residue.

What's going on here?

- Are the pans defective and shouldn't have done that, so we should return them for new ones?
- Am I an idiot for putting somewhat acidic (sourdough, after all) food into a non-stick (steel-base) baking pan?
- Something else?

[image: Crazy metallic-y coating]

Comment: I’ve known sourdough baked in pans to have a very shiny and crust where it was in contact with the pan, but never metallic or the colour of anything but bread crust. I assume the flour was just plain wheat flour etc?

Comment: I'll grab a picture from my wife's phone asap. Bear with me.

Yeah, no fancy weird flour. Just plain or whole wheat. Some sunflower seeds in there as well.

Answer (score 6):

It looks indeed like the Sourdough and the anti-stick disagree with each other... though the extent of it is something I have neither seen nor heard about yet! May be the non-stick version you do have. If the dough was left in the pan to rise for a while, that may have been part of it.
But I have to say, except for the issue with your pan, the bread looks amazing!!!

Comment: Agreed. I have loaf pans that are explicitly labeled as „sourdough proof“.